# continuity of incremental ratio (different quotient)

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that:

1. $f\in\mathcal{C}^2(a,b)$
2. $\lim_{x\to a}f'(x)=+\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to b}f'(x)=-\infty$ or
   $\lim_{x\to a}f'(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to b}f'(x)=+\infty$
3. $f'(x)$ is monotone on $(a,b)$

I want to prove that for every $c\in\mathbb{R}$ there exist $x,y\in[a,b]$ such that

$$
\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}=c
$$

Is the same result true if $f'(x)$ is not monotone?

I think that some kind of inverse Lagrange theorem for derivative should be applied but I have no clear ideas.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $A := \{(x,y) \in (a,b)^2 : x < y\}$. Then the function
$$g: A \to \mathbb{R}, \quad g(x,y) = \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$$
is continuous. As $A$ is connected, $g(A)$ is necessarily an interval. Assume that there is an $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(x,y) \leq M$ for all $(x,y) \in A$. Now choose $x \in (a,b)$ with $f'(x) \geq 2M$, which exists by your assumptions. Then, for $y$ sufficiently close to $x$, we have $|g(x,y) - f'(x)| < \frac{M}{2}$. But this implies $g(x,y) \geq \frac{3M}{2}$. A contradiction. Similarly, you can show that $g$ is not bounded from below. Monotonicity of $f'$ is not needed.

Comment: So simple and clear! Thank you!